Why is wp_remote_get using the wrong port?
I'm sending a query with wp_remote_get() from within a ddev hosted wordpress that runs on port 4430. My hostname contains a port specification (https://host.example:443/bla).
Now the problem is that when the target port for the wp_remote_get() is 443, it is sent to port 4430 instead which results in a 'Connection refused' error.
Other ports seem to work correctly.
Any ideas?

This sounds like a bug in your code. I recommend that you step through the code with xdebug and make sure that the URL is set correctly in wp_remote_get()
